# calico-kube-controllers is in pending state

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to install Kubernetes cluster using this tutorial:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/

But when I install the master place and run: `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` I get:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-555bc4b957-kv6zz   0/1     Pending   0          5m38s
calico-node-kzfqn                          1/1     Running   0          5m38s
coredns-6d4b75cb6d-lwdgx                   1/1     Running   0          6m44s
coredns-6d4b75cb6d-mrkqj                   1/1     Running   0          6m45s
etcd-kubernetes1                           1/1     Running   0          6m50s
kube-apiserver-kubernetes1                 1/1     Running   0          6m50s
kube-controller-manager-kubernetes1        1/1     Running   0          6m52s
kube-proxy-hqgxj                           1/1     Running   0          6m45s
kube-scheduler-kubernetes1                 1/1     Running   0          6m50s
```

events:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                    OBJECT             MESSAGE
7m17s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
7m17s       Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
7m17s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientPID      node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
7m7s        Normal    Starting                  node/kubernetes1   Starting kubelet.
7m7s        Warning   InvalidDiskCapacity       node/kubernetes1   invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
7m7s        Normal    NodeAllocatableEnforced   node/kubernetes1   Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
7m7s        Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
7m7s        Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
7m7s        Normal    NodeHasSufficientPID      node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
7m4s        Normal    RegisteredNode            node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 event: Registered Node kubernetes1 in Controller
6m58s       Normal    Starting                  node/kubernetes1
5m15s       Normal    NodeReady                 node/kubernetes1   Node kubernetes1 status is now: NodeReady
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$
```

Do you know how I can fix `calico-kube-controllers-555bc4b957-kv6zz` to be in Running State?

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl describe pod --namespace kube-system calico-kube-controllers-555bc4b957-kv6zz
Name:                 calico-kube-controllers-555bc4b957-kv6zz
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 <none>
Labels:               k8s-app=calico-kube-controllers
                      pod-template-hash=555bc4b957
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Pending
IP:
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/calico-kube-controllers-555bc4b957
Containers:
  calico-kube-controllers:
    Image:      docker.io/calico/kube-controllers:v3.23.3
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Liveness:   exec [/usr/bin/check-status -l] delay=10s timeout=10s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [/usr/bin/check-status -r] delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      ENABLED_CONTROLLERS:  node
      DATASTORE_TYPE:       kubernetes
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-j2hn7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-j2hn7:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m10s (x3 over 14m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had untolerated taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane: }. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

From the event of the pod you can clearly see that the scheduler was not able to schedule the pod onto the control-plane due to `untolerated taint` on the control plane.

Think of `taints` and `tolerations` as a bug spray (`taint`) and a bug which has a `toleration` to a specific bug spray. Some bugs will tolerate bug sprays that are designed to keep off other species of bugs. In your case, the control plane is tainted with `node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane` and your pod has toleration for `node-role.kubernetes.io/master`. In order to schedule the pod onto the control plane, ensure the pod tolerates the same taints as the target node (controlplane)

Comment: How I can fix this?

Comment: You can edit the pod definition and another toleration to the pod. If you wish to update an existing toleration, it will fail. please refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding a toleration to your pod spec:

```yaml
kind: Pod
...
spec:
 tolerations:
  - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
...
```

Comment: Can you guide me where is this file located and how to restart the service after I edit it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov calico.yaml